# Spring WebFlux thymeleaf error : Could not resolve view with name 'index'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-webflux

Hello i work with Spring WebFlux and i try to integrate thymeleaf to my projet but i got this error :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5kFp.png)

here is my controller :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chDdS.png)

here is my applications.yaml :

```
spring:
  application:
    name: fbpayapi
  thymeleaf:
    prefix: classpath:/templates/
    suffix: .html
  main:
    web-application-type: reactive
  webflux:
    base-path: /api-mgr
  web:
    resources:
      add-mappings: false
```

here is my dependency :

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
                <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            </dependency>
```

here is the index.html in src/main/resources/index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

i tried with @RestController but didnt work also